# Google Oauth is not recognizing www.domain.com and domain.com as the same website

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-platform, web-applications, oauth-2.0

Good Morning, friends!

I have some access issues with my website that is using oauth2. The issue is that when a user login to his/her account in the [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com), they can't access to they account in the domain.com.

Basiclly I have a website in which the user can access via [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) or domain.com and I need the user can login just once, in whatever the url they typed, and this is not happening at this time.

Both url are whitelisted in the URIs inside the Google Cloud Config, so we don't know what is the problem in here.

PD: If some code is required, please let me know, so I can provide it to you. We're developing a vuejs web app.

**EDIT:**

This is the function that handle the users login:

```
handleSuccess(googleUser) {
  this.$parent.userId = googleUser.getBasicProfile().getEmail();
  this.loadStore();
}
```

This is the Google sign-in button we're using:

```
gapi.signin2.render("google-signin-btn", {
  //scope: 'email',
  width: 240,
  height: 50,
  //longtitle: true,
  theme: 'dark',
  onsuccess: this.handleSuccess,
  onfailure: this.handleFailure,
});
```

And this is the config we have on the cloud console:

[I have both URIs in the configs, so what I expected is that when an users login in one of them, they no longer need to aunthenticate on the other one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXGTB.png)

**EDIT 2**

**Import statements:**

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css'
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js'
```

The rest of the imports are just the others vue.js components

**gapi.auth2.init()**

This is the button that Google provides, so the function we're using are hide. This info is more detailed in the google documentations for the button

Comment: code is allways welcome. See [mre]

Comment: Thanks, @T-Me, some code added, just let me know if there would be necessary more details.

Comment: 1) Show the import statements, `gapi.auth2.init()` and code behind the button. 2) The domain authorized in the Google console is not related to the session cookie stored on a user's machine. 3) a cookie stored for `example.com` usually is available for `www.example.com` but not the reverse. This is controlled by `cookiepolicy`.

Comment: Hello, @JohnHanley, thanks for your reply and sorry for the late answer. I already edited the post with the info you were asking for. The cookie fact wasn't in my knowledge, I'll revise it to properly handle those cookies.